# SQL oracle - Delete Duplicate Records and update records in other table

Tags: sql, oracle

Requirement - Delete Duplicate records e.g. from 2 tables and update the records in the other tables.

**Input**

```
Table1   Dim_Ctry   

PK_Key1 Country 
100     Argentina   
200     ARGENTINA   
300     India   
400     INDIA   

Table2  Dim_Geo     

PK_Key2  Geo    
500      Globe  
600      GLOBE  
700      Market 
800      MARKET 
900      Unique 

Table   Fact1   

PK_Key15    FK_KEY1 FK_KEY2
1           100     500
2           200     600
3           300     800
4           400     900

Table   Fact2   

PK_Key16    FK_KEY1 FK_KEY2
5           100     500
6           200     600
7           200     700
8           300     800
```

**output**

```
Table1   Dim_Ctry           

PK_Key1 Country     
100     Argentina                   
300     India               

Table2   Dim_Geo        

PK_Key2  Geo        
500      Globe              
700      Market     
900      Unique     

Table   Fact1       

PK_Key15    FK_KEY1 FK_KEY2 
1           100     500 
2           100     500 
3           300     800 
4           300     800 

Table   Fact2       

PK_Key16    FK_KEY1 FK_KEY2 comment
5           100     500 
6           100     500 
7           100     700 
7           300     800 
8           1000    2000    no record in dim table just retain
```

Comment: It is unclear exactly what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to delete from 2 tables and place the deleted rows in another table?

Comment: i don't see you remove duplicates between your input and output samples.

Comment: Yes. That is True. Please refer the data how the output looks like.

Comment: refer what data? Please edit your question properly.

Comment: Sorry Juan, I strike it in xl and copy pasted, will correct output.

Comment: Thanks, you should also comment on what changes between input and output. Because still isnt clear when update and when delete.

Answer (score 0):

You will need several steps.

- Step 1 update related tables

Update all `FK_KEY` to the min value.

```
UPDATE Fact1 f1
SET 
FK_KEY1 = (SELECT MIN(PK_Key1)
           FROM Dim_Ctry dc1
           WHERE UPPER(dc1.Country) = (SELECT UPPER(dc2.Country)
                                       FROM Dim_Ctry dc2
                                       WHERE dc2.PK_Key1 = f1.FK_KEY1)
          ),
FK_KEY2 = (SELECT MIN(PK_Key2)
           FROM Dim_Geo dg1
           WHERE UPPER(dg1.Geo) = (SELECT UPPER(dg2.Geo)
                                   FROM Dim_Geo dg2
                                   WHERE dg2.PK_Key2 = f1.FK_KEY2)
          );
```

- Step 2 delete duplicated

This will delete all duplicated and keep the one with smaller id

```
DELETE FROM Dim_Ctry dc1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT PK_Key1 
              FROM Dim_Ctry  dc2
              WHERE dc1.PK_Key1 > dc2.PK_Key1 
              and  UPPER(dc1.Country) = UPPER(dc2.Country)
```

- Step 3 update the text

You should update to lower or upper to standard format.

```
UPDATE Dim_Ctry
SET Country = UPPER(Country)
```

**debug query**

```
SELECT f1.PK_Key15, f1.FK_KEY1, f1.FK_KEY2, 
             (SELECT UPPER(dc2.Country) 
              FROM Dim_Ctry dc2 
              WHERE dc2.PK_Key1 = f1.FK_KEY1
              ) as CurrentName,
              (SELECT MIN(PK_Key1) 
               FROM Dim_Ctry dc1 
               WHERE UPPER(dc1.Country) = (SELECT UPPER(dc2.Country) FROM Dim_Ctry dc2 WHERE dc2.PK_Key1 = f1.FK_KEY1) ) as minKey
FROM Fact1 f1
```

Comment: The last row on `Fact2` why say 1000 and 2000?. I discard that result, I guess was a typo.

Comment: I just kept it as there might be some records which not there in dimensional tables. I think it will not have any impact.

Comment: UPDATE Fact1 f1
SET 
FK_KEY1 = (SELECT MIN(PK_Key1)
           FROM Dim_Ctry dc1
           WHERE UPPER(dc1.Country) = (SELECT UPPER(dc2.Country)
                                       FROM Dim_Ctry dc2
                                       WHERE dc2.PK_Key1 = f1.FK_KEY1)
          ); I'm getting error -  Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01407: cannot update ( "FACT_tableT"."FKDIM_key ") to NULL
01407. 00000 -  "cannot update (%s) to NULL"  - Juan could you please help with this error, I don't think that we are trying to insert null but still it gives error.

Comment: I include a debug SELECT so you test your data. CurrentName and minKey shouldn't be `null`. Let me know the result

Comment: Thanks. We are dealing with only 1 column in fact table so removed the f1.fk_key2. I executed the debug and millions records are there. Is there way to check only for Nulls?

Comment: I copied result to spread sheet and see some nulls for CURRENTNAME and minimum key.

Comment: Did you solve it? looks like is an error on the data tables.  You could copy the inner select into a clausule `where (select ... ) is null`

Comment: Sorry for the Delay - Will Test it and get back to you.